# Extract data from string using regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need string with brackes from one string using regex.
My string will be like: Node{id}data_{name}key

So I need id and name with comma seperated
Result: id, name.

Can I have regex expression for the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
Node{+(?<id>[0-9]*)+}data_{+(?<name>[a-zA-Z]*)}key
```

You tagged with C# so how about code something like the following (not tested)

```
Regex exp = new Regex(@"Node{+(?<id>[0-9]*)+}data_{+(?<name>[a-zA-Z]*)}key", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection matchList = exp.Matches(yourString);
string id = matchList.Groups["id"].Value;
string name = matchList.Groups["name"].Value;
//build up whatever string you like
return String.Format("{0},{1}", id, name);
```

Comment: No worries. How about a tick? :)

Comment: out of curiosity and in case anyone's listening, will the same pattern work in Java?

Comment: It should, it's just regex

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with only one regex. However you can extract the list of strings within braces by matching against `\{([^}]+)\}` in a loop, extract `\1` and put it into an array.

Then join the elements of the array with `,` and you will have your result.